# Fade-in/Fade-out effect with CSS

Tags: html, css, animation

I can't seem to get transition effect working using CSS. I would like to have my drop-down menu fade-in slowinly and fade-out slowly when user clicks. The menu is constructed using ul element and the initial state is hidden. The hidden state is made possible by CSS style and so is visible state. The two styles are toggled using javascript.

This is my CSS style :

```
.username-menu-hidden {
   opacity: 0;
   transition: visibility 0s 2s, opacity 2s linear; 
   display: none; 
}

.username-menu-visible {
   opacity: 1;
   transition: opacity 6s linear;   
   display: block; 
}
```

This is menu :

```
<ul class="username-menu username-menu-hidden" id="user-menu">
```

Onclick function is working and it replaced "username-menu-hiddne" with "username-menu-visible". It just that there is no transition effect. The menu just appears right away.

P.S : I'm limited to CSS. I can't use JQuery.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $("element").fadeIn();
});
```

This is what you are looking for.

You can try using [jquery.](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/)

Else you can use webkit opacity fade.

```
function clickeventhandler(evt){
    var element = document.getElementById(evt.target.id);
    fade(element);

}
```

Comment: Nope, I'm not allowed to use jquery.

Comment: But do you know why my css is not working as expected?

Comment: @user30646.: Maybe there is some compatibily issue with browser,...check it first.

Answer (score 1):

user30646, your CSS looks great, except use "visibility" instead of "display". Here's a working example:

```
<a href="javascript:void();" onclick="openMenu();">Top level</a>
<ul class="username-menu username-menu-hidden" id="user-menu">
    <li>Second level</li>
</ul>

<script>
function openMenu() {
    myButtonClasses.add("username-menu-visible");
}
var myButtonClasses = document.getElementById("user-menu").classList;
</script>

<style>
.username-menu-hidden {
   opacity: 0;
   transition: visibility 0s 2s, opacity 2s linear; 
   visibility:hidden;
}
.username-menu-visible {
   opacity: 1;
   transition: opacity 6s linear;   
   visibility:visible;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I can't get visibility work. The menu won't even show up if I use visibility instead of display. Do you know what could be the cause?

Answer (score 0):

Now it can be achieved in css directly.

Let say something is triggering this `isExpanded` variable:

```
 <ul
    className={`menu  absolute w-full z-10  ${
      !isExpanded ? 'hide' : 'show'
    }`}>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
  </ul>
```

Css:

```
@keyframes fade-out {
  to {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes fade-in {
  from {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.menu.show {
  animation: fade-in 0.2s forwards;
}

.menu.hide {
  animation: fade-out 0.2s forwards;
}
```